# How to build polymer projects in dart editor?

Tags: dart, dart-polymer

I have a branch [here](https://github.com/0xor1/purity_stopwatch_example/tree/polymer) where I am trying out using the polymer tutorial example stopwatch with my own client-server framework. I have made the changes I thought I needed to make and if I run any of the html files in `test/integration` folder directly with dart editor dartium opens up and everything works as expected. If I then right click on my pubspec.yaml file and do `pub build`, the build succeeds but trying to run any of the relevant html files in the `build\test\integration` folder I get lots of odd errors in a dialog saying pub server could not be started, because the html import urls in the `purity_stopwatch.html` file are incorrect, even though it works when running directly from the project. Any help would be much appreciated Im very new to polymer and not familiar with the conventional usage/build practices.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I guess the problem is that the browser can't access the files.
Either you use any web server that serves the files to the browser or
you start the browser (if it is Chrome) with the command line argument `--allow-file-access-from-files`